# Bash - How to store a list of directories sorted by timestamp of directory creation

Tags: bash

I have a list of directories that I am iterating over to save into a list like so

```
dirs=''
for d in */ ; do
  dir_name=${d%/}

  tag="foobar:${dir_name}-${sha1}"

  dirs+="{\"app_image\":\"${tag}\",\"dir_name\":\"${dir_name}\"},"
done
```

but instead of `*/` is it possible to iterate over a list of directories sorted by the directory creation timestamp? I'd like this list to always have new directories appended to the end of the list, rather than the list being sorted alphabetically

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, directory creation time may not be available. The repository is version controlled through git so I'll check out git commands in the mean time to see if that helps otherwise I'll look into a hackier workaround

Comment: Are you trying to create a JSON data?

Comment: I'm trying to create a list and of objects (that look like json?) to pass into terraform. Right now terraform is acting up when an element is added to the middle of the list so I have a hypothesis that only appending entries (keeping most of the list static) will avoid unnecessary resource recreation @LéaGris

Comment: Are you using a filesystem that tracks creation/birth times and an OS and tools that let you query that value?

Comment: I'm on mac and I can see the timestamp in the output of `ls -lah`

Comment: I vote to close the question because it lacks debugging details and enough information like requirements. Don't attempt to help or you will get negative feed-back.

Comment: Your answer talks about creating a json list but does not answer the question of "How to store a list of directories sorted by timestamp of directory creation" which actually does not ask about json at all. My previous comment in this thread also does not say I care about json in particular

Comment: Actually I may have misunderstood what's in the output of `ls -lah` . As you point out @Shawn Creation time may not actually be available according to the answers here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20464/210668

In which case, the repository is version controlled through git so hopefully there are git commands available to get that information

Answer (score 0):

This would output a JSON reassembling your output but entirely in `jq`:

It builds arguments to `jq` with dirs

```js
jq -n '
# Start a JSON array
[
  # Handle each positional argument
  # remove trailing slash /
  $ARGS.positional[] | rtrimstr("/") | {
    # Starting a new Object with app_image and dir_name
    # Compose app_image tag using dir name and sha1 argument
    "app_image": ( "foobar:" + . + "-" + $sha1 ),
    # same with dire_name
    "dir_name": . }
]' \
--arg sha1 "aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d" \
--args */
```

Comment: The part I care about most in the question is a list ordered by created at timestamp. Not processing a list of directories into json

Comment: @irregular Your question expose none of these requirements. Don't expect people to help you with things you don't tell or have telepathic aptitude to read your mind.

Comment: The question says "How to store a list of directories sorted by timestamp of directory creation", not how to create a list of json objects so the json part isn't essential to the question